Partial Power Query transposition so that captions remain
Novice power query user here. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with the following problem. I'm tasked with modifying an excel template that is roughly of that format:



City
Borough
Street
House
Attribute1
Attribute2
Attribute3
Attribute4




New York
Manhattan
W111
102
1
2
3
4


New York
Manhattan
W109
58
11
22
33
44


New York
Brooklyn
E49
56
111
222
333
444


New York
Brooklyn
E49
24
1111
2222
3333
4444



The thing is, it is highly likely that there will be more attributes in the future, so it was decided that we should transpose the template to the following format:




City
Borough
Street
House
Value




Attribute1
New York
Manhattan
W111
102
1


Attribute1
New York
Manhattan
W109
58
11


Attribute1
New York
Brooklyn
E49
56
111


Attribute1
New York
Brooklyn
E49
24
1111


Attribute2
New York
Manhattan
W111
102
2


Attribute2
New York
Manhattan
W109
58
22


Attribute2
New York
Brooklyn
E49
56
222


Attribute2
New York
Brooklyn
E49
24
2222


Attribute3
New York
Manhattan
W111
102
3


Attribute3
New York
Manhattan
W109
58
33


Attribute3
New York
Brooklyn
E49
56
333


Attribute3
New York
Brooklyn
E49
24
3333


Attribute4
New York
Manhattan
W111
102
4


Attribute4
New York
Manhattan
W109
58
44


Attribute4
New York
Brooklyn
E49
56
444


Attribute4
New York
Brooklyn
E49
24
4444



The idea is that business users will continue to fill it the way they are used to and I should implement a power query script that converts it for our backend convenience and that is not tied to a fixed number of attribute columns.
I watched some YT tutorials and tried removing row with captions (so that the captions don't get transposed alongside with the values) and merging all the attribute columns into one with a delimiter, then unmerging them using that delimiter to rows; this idea seems to have potential: I end up with a single column containing all the values, however what is missing is attribute names and plain values can't be used without names. It would be ideal to have a leftmost column with attribute captions, as in the example. Also I can't manage to force PQ to get all the columns starting with "Attribute1" till the rightmost end, tried to do something with List.Select-ing all columns then excluding the ones that should stay, but I couldn't beat that yet, too.
I would greatly appreciate if anybody could help me with that problem. Thanks in advance!

Load your data into Power Query - Data --> From table/range

Select City, Borough, Street, House, (use Ctrl-left click to select multiple columns), right click and select "Unpivot other columns"

Rearrange the columns if required:


Michael, that turned out to be really easy, thank you very much and please excuse my noob question.

@Alexander Welcome, no reason to apologise. We all learn. I have asked much simpler questions in the past.
